# What is Change Detection in Angular2?

Tags: angular, zonejs

What is the Change Detection that mentioned [here](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/zones/) for Angular 2? How ZoneJS doing that in Angular 2.

UPDATE: What do you mean when you say 'Change Detection'? Is it to detect the changes in the data or the DOM elements?

Comment: Some of the links 
https://auth0.com/blog/understanding-angular-2-change-detection/
https://pascalprecht.github.io/slides/angular-2-change-detection-explained/#/

Comment: As for the zones, see this http://blog.kwintenp.com/how-the-hell-do-zones-really-work/